# SQL SERVER Convert Date Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, date-format

Now in the column store string in three different format. Example such

- 2/04/15 9.30-12
- 10/01/2015 10am - 1pm
- 17/03/15 1st appt

How can I to convert the all the date to consolidate to stardard date like ddmmyyy? Use Left 10 is not appropriate.

Comment: Don't store dates as text. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

Following is my solution for SQL2012:

```
DECLARE @Date AS TABLE(val VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO @Date VALUES('2/04/15 9.30-12');
INSERT INTO @Date VALUES('10/01/2015 10am - 1pm');
INSERT INTO @Date VALUES('17/03/15 1st appt');

SELECT TRY_PARSE(LEFT(val, CHARINDEX(' ', val)) AS DATE USING 'en-gb') AS Date FROM @Date;
```

And the output is:

[image]

Will try to find out something for 2008 too. possibly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try_convert()`.  And then `try_convert()` again.  Perhaps something like:

```
select coalesce(try_convert(date, left(col, charindex(' ', col + ' ') - 1), 1),
                try_convert(date, left(col, charindex(' ', col + ' ') - 1), 101),
                try_convert(date, left(col, charindex(' ', col + ' ') - 1), 103),
                . . .
               ) as dte
from t;
```

Just keep trying different styles.  Be careful that these are ordered.  So, you have to decide if `02/01/2012` is February 1st or January 2nd.

Comment: from sql server 2012

Comment: any ways deal with sql server 2008?